# access user profile via oauth tokens passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, passport.js

I have been using [passport.js](http://passportjs.org). It works and I am able to get the `oauth_token` and `Verifier` easily from APIs.

In passport.js each API has a strategy which basically decide how to communicate with that API server. At the end a callback to get returned user profile.

But I saw no way to use `oauth_token` to get the `profile` myself. Its a one time shot at the end of Oauth authentication to save data in session or db.

Is there any way I can use my `oauth_token` to directly access the user profile any time usingpassport methods.

*In prototype I saw `userProfile` function which does what I need but its a private method somehow. I don't know how to use it*

**Update 1**

I have been scavenging the git repo for passport.js , I come to know they use the "`node-oauth`" to manage calls to the API servers. This is available in any strategies `_oauth`.

But I am not aware what calls to make to get resource token. Also I have to initiate all API calls in callbacks step by step to imitate the token access calls. Is there any standard way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Without digging into the code (but having used Passport before) I'm assuming that the `oauth_token` is being stored with the user data in your database.  You may have to access your database models directly in order to get the token, then you can use it with the provider APIs to get access to the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Visit following page to get a grasp of how to use the _oauth property.

https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth

It works like this:

```
oauth.get(
  'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=23424977',
  'your user token for this app', //test user token
  'your user secret for this app', //test user secret            
  function (e, data, res){
    if (e) console.error(e);        
    console.log(require('util').inspect(data));
    done();      
  });
```

In case you implement your own OAuth1.0 strategy you easily could overwrite
following method to implement your own logic for fetching the profile data from the remote OAuth server:

```
/**
 * @overwritten 
 * @method userProfile 
 * @class OAuth1Strategy
 * @description used by OAuth1Strategy class while authenticating 
 *  to get the user profile from the server 
 */
OAuth1Strategy.prototype.userProfile = 
 function(token, tokenSecret, params, done) {

  this._oauth.get(
    config.profileUrl,
     token, 
    tokenSecret,         
    function (e, data, res){
      if (e) console.error(e);        
      console.log(require('util').inspect(data));
      done(e, data);      
    }); 
};
```